# How to download the development files from the Wordpress Admin panel?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I download all the web development files when I been given access as an admin to the site via the WP admin panel? Do I need to do so via the hosting server or can it be done via wp-admin? I need the development files so I may start modifying the HTML, CSS, JS files.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it through an ftp client such as [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en) or [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org). You can edit a lot of the themes PHP and CSS through the admin panel by going to Appearance > Editor.

As far as downloading and creating custom files you will need to use FTP or have access to the sites cpanel or hosting site.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

i don't get your question, i mean, to edit some files or "parts" of your wordpress site, you can access, as administrator, to Appearance/customize right there check the theme you are using and customize it! also use some plugins, too, you can customize your main menu, footer, buttons, etc.

Or

if you want to edit them with notepad++ or something, you can download them using a FTP software like filezilla, just enter your domain, user and password to enter your website and drop the file you want to edit to your desktop o everywhere you want.

good luck,see ya.

pd: if that's not what you are looking for, change your question to help you